# How to echo a language's name using the 'raw' attribute?

Tags: php, polylang

I'd like to make a language switcher, but the default options don't work for me, so I'd like to use the 'raw' attribute. I'm currently just testing whether my languages will show up at all:

```php
$translations = pll_the_languages(array('raw'=>1));
echo $translations[0]['name'];
```

This code doesn't output anything, but doesn't crash the website either. What am I missing?

Comment: `pll_the_languages(array('raw'=>1));` what does this return?\

Comment: That simply returns the word 'Array'.

Comment: `print_r($translations);` and share the output here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4UyYnPuF
Looks exactly like what I need... but the above code still won't output anything.

Comment: which info do you need?

Comment: I want to use this function to make a language switcher at the top of my screen. So for now, I was just trying to get any kind of output out of it. I was wondering what was wrong with my first attempt.

Comment: I posted an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to get it like this:

```
echo $translations['nl']['name'];
```

It's better to verify if the key exists in the array or not.

```
$value= "";
if($key_exists('nl',$translations) && $key_exists('name',$translations['nl'])){
$value = $translations['nl']['name'];
}
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$translations = pll_the_languages(array('raw'=>1));
echo $translations[nl][name];
```

I thought the second array would be named after the 'order' number of the language, turns out it was the slug. Thanks to Danyal for helping me find the array's framework.